# I want to find a formula to find the mode of the highlighted cells in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, dynamic-programming, conditional-formatting, mode

I am trying to find a formula to find the mode of the highlighted cells. The value inside cell D13 will determine the number of highlighted cells. If it is 3, 3 rows will be highlighted starting from cell H3. For example, if the highlighted cell contains 3 values B, B, and A. B will be returned to cell C13 as the mode value. I have attached a screenshot of my Excel, anyone can help me?[image: This is the screenshot of my progress so far]

Comment: Do you want highlight cells or want to return most occurrence alphabet?

Comment: I want to return the most occurrence alphabet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *"I want to return the most occurrence alphabet."*

You could use:

[image]

```
=LET(r,TAKE(H3:H10,D13),@SORTBY(r,COUNTIF(r,r),-1))
```

Comment: WoW! That is much more simpler.

Comment: Looks much simpler, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Give a try to the following formula.

```
=LET(
x,INDEX(H3:H10,SEQUENCE(D13)),
y,UNIQUE(x),
z,MAP(y,LAMBDA(t,SUM(--(x=t)))),
TAKE(SORTBY(y,z,-1),1)
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with conditional formatting.  For each cell in column H, comparing the matching value in the Row column (A) with the value in $D$13.  If Row value is <= $D$13 then format background colour.  In my sheet cell C9 is a named range 'Select'.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I managed to do that. I am figuring out how to return the most-occurrence alphabet in the highlighted cells.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you should realise about conditional formatting: it reads the value of a cell and as a result of that, it alters a formatting (like the background fill, which looks like highlighting).
I have the impression that you want to do just the opposite: read the formatting (like the highlighting) and as a result of that, change a value.

This is not the way conditional formatting works, and if this is indeed what you need, you might be forced to look for a VBA solution for that.